# Elementwise on Dataframe with external condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames with identical shapes and columns. I'd like to apply map for first DataFrame depending on the following condition : if x < y then I apply ceil operation else floor.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0.9, 8.1, 4.3], 'b' : [1.9, 1.4, 2.5], 'c' : [2.9, 1.2, 2.3]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,   2,   3  ], 'b' : [2,   1,   5],    'c' : [2,   0,   3]})
```

As output I want to receive the following DataFrame:

```
z = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,   8,   4  ], 'b' : [2,   1,   3],    'c' : [2,   1,   3]})
```

Please assist me how I could do it...

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `np.where`:

```
z = pd.DataFrame(np.where(x<y, np.ceil(x), np.floor(x)).astype(int),
                 index=x.index,
                 columns=x.columns)
```

Or Pandas' `where`:

```
z = np.ceil(x).where(x<y, np.floor(x)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   2
1   8   1   1
2   4   3   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
z = pd.DataFrame(np.where(x<y, np.ceil(x), np.floor(x)), 
                 dtype='int', 
                 columns=x.columns, 
                 index=x.index)
```

---

```
print(z)  
   a  b  c
0  1  2  2
1  8  1  1
2  4  3  3
```